# How to Loop Parsed Json Response on Ansible

Tags: json, parsing, ansible, yaml

I'm working on a playbook and I'm waiting for this playbook to collect web requests and generate an output. Since I am making requests to multiple interfaces I need to split that. How could I do that?

```
  tasks:
  - name: Collecting Endpoints
    uri:
      url: "https://applicationserver.com/api/app_set"
      method: GET
      return_content: yes
      validate_certs : no
      body_format: json
    register: Result

  - name: Temp to variable.
    set_fact:
      Endpoint: "{{ Result.json | json_query('[].name[]') }}"
```

Here is my response from the first task https://paste.chapril.org/?142535f7072d47ed#4TahPDaDGPkP1NxxB3gzZP86SkusJ9Kk6jSfqmSy7wK7

According to the data I have collected from the first task, I want to request each one-by-one filter data from within.

This is the JSON response of any of my endpoints. https://paste.chapril.org/?44e8f5462b105285#E2J7LzRwWSCJXR8BetzB1pewnV2ye1Fr1g741VacwBJb

```
- name: Get Responses All.
    uri:
       url: "https://applicationserver.com/api/app_set/{{ item }}"
       method: GET
       return_content: yes
       body_format: json
       validate_certs : no
    register: Resultsofall
    loop: "{{ Endpoint }}"
```

After this task, I am receiving all Json datas of all endpoints.

How can I filter the data from the whole result and loop like that?

`app_sets`    
 `Index 1 (Which is counting by  endpoint)`  
 `AppSetName (Getting from the first task (json_query('[].name[]')`  
 `StatefulAppSetName (Getting from the first task( ('[].labels[].AttachedToStatefulAppSet[]'))`
   `Apps  (Getting from the second task json_query('[].json.pods.app')`

`Index 2 (Which is counting by  endpoint)`  
 `AppSetName (Getting from the first task (json_query('[].name[]')`  
 `StatefulAppSetName (Getting from the first task( ('[].labels[].AttachedToStatefulAppSet[]'))`
   `Apps  (Getting from the second task json_query('[].json.pods.app')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your json_query right, which is based on [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/). Assuming you're interested on the name of the your services in your json your query should be:

```
  - name: Temp to variable.
    set_fact:
      Endpoint: "{{ Result.json | json_query('services[].app') }}"
```

If you are interested in services and pods you could de something like

```
  - name: Temp to variable.
    set_fact:
      services_apps: "{{ Result.json | json_query('services[].app') }}"  
      pods_apps: "{{ Result.json | json_query('services[].app') }}"
  - name: Get Responses All.
    uri:
       url: "https://applicationserver.com/api/app_set/{{ item }}"
       method: GET
       return_content: yes
       body_format: json
       validate_certs : no
    register: Resultsofall
    loop: "{{ (services_apps + pods_apps )| unique | select | list }}"
```

I recommend using https://jmespath.org/ to develop and test you queries.

Comment: Actually, I want to list the app tags for each endpoint separately. Which is getting with 'results[*].json[].pods[].[tag]'. Looped URI task collects all values for all URI. I want to split that